# In and Out of Bounds: Pricing, Marketing, etc

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, close-reasons, questions

This site is going to attract questions by ebook authors about pricing, marketing, search engine optimization, and the like. In my opinion, those questions are squarely out of bounds for this site. That said, I am not aware of any sites in the Stack Exchange network which are good candidates for such questions.

Are such questions proper here? If not, should they simply be closed, or is there a site in the network to which they might be referred/migrated?

Comment: Another related category is the [guidelines of ebook sellers](http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/79/what-triggers-the-adult-designation-on-amazon-kindle-books-romance-genre).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's tackle one problem at a time.  Right now, our problem is to collect a good set of expert answers to ebook questions.  It's *way* too early to worry about keeping out hoards of authors.  But when authors *do* stop by to ask questions that don't *quite* fit in or when they don't get helpful answers, feel free to point them to [Writers](https://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Questions on these topics are welcome here:
>
> ...
>
> - Professional-level blogging
> - The publishing and editing process itself

I would imagine that there is some overlap between the sites, but I hope *this* site will develop it's own culture.

Comment: The overlap being on the writing of ebooks seems like the key factor

Comment: @jon, Fair enough, and thanks for taking the time to answer. I haven't participated in a beta for one of these sites before, so I'm not sure at what point we need to address these questions.

Comment: @Ed Cottrell: No worries. Welcome to your first private beta! Have you read [Respect the community](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/)?  It explains some of our philosophy of overlapping topics.

Comment: I have, thanks! I have been a longtime consumer of Stack Exchange sites, but have just recently gotten active on them, and am really glad I did. Great communities here.

Answer (score 2):

We should focus on reading and authoring. The current [business sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites#business-users) in our network don’t seem to fit, and [Onstartups was closed](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business) (not enough questions!), so there seems to be no other site for those questions.

Comment: The reasons for Answers OnStartup's closure are... more complicated than a lack of questions.

Answer (score 2):

I think that we should support author's questions. This site is very limited in scope, so let's not limit it more. If they specifically relate to ebook publishing (not books in general), than they belong here.

Comment: especially since it is much easier to go from epub to paper than the other way around.

Comment: @hildred You probably ment actual paper. but if you still have your word document. (for your own good, always keep it.) the other way should be easier.