# Should we make questions pertaining to business of publishing free e-books in-scope?

Tags: discussion

There seems to be a feeling that marketing and sales may be out of scope for this site (see proposal [here](https://ebooks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/in-and-out-of-bounds-pricing-marketing-etc)) as well as one proposal in [general offtopic thread](https://ebooks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-issues-are-candidates-for-off-topic-reasons-for-the-site) by Grant Palin).

While there doesn't seem to be consensus on these proposals yet, I would like to propose that we consider a more well defined sub-set of those questions to be a candidate for being on-topic.

More specifically, **should we include as on-topic the questions that pertain to publishing business that related to free-as-in-beer published books, used as a business tactics**?

*Please note that making them in-scope would NOT mean that 100% of them would be allowed - as usual, a question would be closed if it asks for discussion or opinions instead of factual answer*.

Comment: NOTE to voters: the question itself doesn't take a position "yes"/"no". I will publish my own answer in support of "yes" position.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, we should include such questions as on-topic (questions about publishing business that relates to free-as-in-beer published books, used as a business tactics).

The reasons to do that are as follows:

1. These questions are a good fit for StackExchange network.

   - They require expert level knowledge
   - They can be answered with a canonical answer citing facts and figures which can be judged to be correct or incorrect.
   - They aren't inherently prone to discussions, opinions, or lists.

     (just to be clear - if a question is asked on this topic that is an opinion question, it should and would still be closed, as opinion based).
2. These questions are relevant to many people interested in e-books, BOTH publishers and consumers.
3. There are no better places on internet (StackExchange or elsewhere) to get this information.

Example of answerable questions on the topic:

- [How beneficial was the Baen Free Library to Baen publishing?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/236/how-beneficial-was-the-baen-free-library-to-baen-publishing)